# Como usar C en Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2022

Quiero aprender a usar C en Visual Studio2022 pero cuando pongo este codigo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int numero1 = 10;
   int numero2 = 5;
   int resultado;

   resultado = numero1 + numero2;

   printf("La suma de %d y %d es %d\n", numero1, numero2, resultado);

   return 0;
}
```

Me salen todas las líneas en rojo.
No se como debo configurar el Visual Studio para poder programas en C

Esto me sale al tratar de ejecutarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Por la información que da la imagen, el código está en un archivo **.cs** correspondiente a C#.

Tiene sentido que obtengas errores ya que, aunque hay ciertas similitudes entre ambos lenguajes, el código en los archivos de C# debe estar solo dentro de clases.

---

Para desarrollar en C++ en Visual Studio necesitas tener las herramientas adecuadas.

Puedes adquirirlas desde el instalador de Visual Studio. Allí marca la casilla de la carga de trabajo de **Desarrollo para el escritorio con C++** y dale clic a **Instalar**.

[image: Captura del instalador]

Una vez que cuentes con las herramientas, crea un nuevo proyecto y filtra los de C++. Puede ser uno vacío, uno de consola o el que prefieras.

Ahora que tienes el proyecto creado sí puedes empezar a escribir código de C++.

Nota que las extensiones compatibles son **.cpp**, **.cxx**, **.hpp** y las de C, **.c**, **.h**.

Puedes consultar más información sobre la [creación de proyectos de C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/using-the-visual-studio-ide-for-cpp-desktop-development?view=msvc-170) en el [sitio oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/?view=msvc-170).

El propósito de la respuesta es ser una pequeña guía. Si necesitas una explicación más detallada puedes ir a la documentación o encontrar algún vídeo/tutorial en internet.

Comment: Tengo instalada lo que me has dicho pero al crear un proyecto me sale un archivo .cs  por lo que los borre y me cree uno .c pero aún así me sale el error que menciono.

Comment: @Rosa sin más información no te puedo ayudar.

Answer (score -1):

Debes asegurarte de tener instalado `gcc` para poder ejecutar en el lenguaje C. Una vez lo tengas supongamos que guardas el código en el archivo `entrada.c`; la forma de compilar es escribiendo en la terminal

```bash
gcc entrada.c
```

en la carpeta que estés encontrarás el ejecutable `a.out`, y aquí lo ejecutas en la terminal `./a.out`, y ya encuentras la salida deseada.